# How can to stop the "ding" sound while pressing enter

Tags: vb.net

I need to stop the "ding" sound while pressing enter but I use it to send a message. There is my code:

```
    Private Sub textbox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
 Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        TextBox3.ReadOnly = True
        If TextBox2.Text = ("") Then
        Else
            Dim PostData = "token=" & TextBox1.Text & "&msg=" & TextBox3.Text & ": " & TextBox2.Text
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://url.com/msg.php")

            request.Method = "POST"
            Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData)
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
            Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
            dataStream.Close()
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
            Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            reader.Close()
            dataStream.Close()
            response.Close()
            TextBox2.Clear()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm using an another sound to notify when a textbox changed but this textbox2 is for sending messages and when it sends it using enter this "ding" plays and the other sound together.

Comment: Does this code really have anything to do with the sound?  If the sound is one of the Windows sounds, then the code is somewhat irrelevant.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `e.Handled` and `e.SuppressKeyPress` to `True`.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        ' Your code...

        e.Handled = True
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This should suppress the "ding".

Answer (score 0):

And if you are using c#

```
    private void numericUpDown4_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        ...
    }
```

Hope it was helpful