# How to suppress annoying beep when user presses Enter on a textbox control?

Tags: vb.net

In VS2019/Visual Basic, how do I suppress the bell (beep) that occurs when a user enters data in a textbox control?

Here's the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub TxtJumpTo_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtJumpTo.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Cr Then
            'Do things
            Else
                'Else do other things
            End If
            'Reset the text box
            TxtJumpTo.Text = ""
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30530750/14171304 ... Also you have the `e.Handled` property in the `KeyPressEventArgs`.

Comment: ...except you just need `e.SuppressKeyPress = True`, since this also sets `e.Handle = true` on its own.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your guidance. When I add that code, VS throws this error:
BC30456 'SuppressKeyPress' is not a member of 'KeyPressEventArgs'.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. I added e.Handled = True but did not add e.SuppressKeyPress = True and the bell is suppressed.

I am still curious about the error message but wasn't able to find anything that explained it well.

Thank you both for responding and your advice. Got me over the finish line.